# How to write inner query or nested query in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to write 'select' inside 'select' (inner query) in following query. the inner query would be for counting like this:
 **select count('id') from order where memb_id = 2;**

and query is:

```
$payment_pending_report = DB::connection('mysql_freesubs')->table('contact as c')
                                        ->select("a.name","c.lname","a.amount as pending amount")             
                                        ->join("member AS m", "c.id", "=", "m.cont_id")
                                        ->join("order AS o", "o.memb_id", "=", "m.id")
                                        ->join("account AS a", "c.id", "=", "a.cont_id")
                                        ->where("a.amount_type", "=","dr")
                                        ->get();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$payment_pending_report = DB::connection('mysql_freesubs')->table('contact as c')
                                    ->select("a.name","c.lname","a.amount as pending amount", "oc.OrderCount as order_count")             
                                    ->join("member AS m", "c.id", "=", "m.cont_id")
                                    ->join("order AS o", "o.memb_id", "=", "m.id")
                                    ->join("account AS a", "c.id", "=", "a.cont_id")
                                    ->join(DB::raw("(SELECT m.id, COUNT(o.some_unique_id) as OrderCount FROM member as m INNER JOIN order as o ON o.memb_id = m.id GROUP BY m.id) AS oc"), function($join)
                                    {
                                        $join->on('m.id', '=', 'oc.id');
                                    })
                                    ->join("(")
                                    ->where("a.amount_type", "=","dr")
                                    ->get();
```

Comment: If you're going to -1 me, at least tell me why.

Comment: Don't use raw queries